# component in react native gets updated itself in RefreshControl

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

So I am trying to implement a pull to refresh feature in my app. And to say I have successfully implemented this in my Android platform where (in simulator) If I pull down (by mouse) then the refreshing indicator will stay visible until I leave the mouse click and the component will not update until the mouse click as well. It will update the component view when I leave the mouse click and refreshing indicator will be hidden in 2 sec. The similar thing is not exactly working as expected in ios, so when I pull down the screen, the component somehow updates even when I haven't left the mouse click. I have given it a googling but probably haven't been able to find the right search keyword.

Below is code snippet of mine. Thanks in advance.

```
render() {
const { loadingCart } = this.props;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView
      style={styles.scrollView}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
      horizontal={false}
      refreshControl={this._renderRefreshingControl()}
    >
      {this._renderProduct()}
      {loadingCart && this._renderLoadingCart()}
    </ScrollView>
    {this._renderCartButton()}
    {this._renderAddToCartPopover()}
  </View>
);
```

}

```
_renderRefreshingControl = () => {
const { refreshing } = this.state;

return (
  <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={this._handleRefreshingControlVisibility} />
);
```

};

```
_handleRefreshingControlVisibility = async () => {
const { fetchProductByCode, navigation } = this.props;
this.setState({
  refreshing: true,
});

const resultAction = await fetchProductByCode('38186');

if (resultAction.type === PRODUCT_FETCH_SUCCESS || resultAction.type === PRODUCT_FETCH_FAILURE) {
  this.setState({
    refreshing: false,
  });
};
```

};

I hope I have been able to clarify my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
_handleRefreshingControlVisibility = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });

    setTimeout(function() {
        // here do what you want
    }, 1500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `RefreshControl` was working as expected, I had a `loading` flag in my render method, somehow this would be set to false when then `refreshing` is set true in `this.setState({ refreshing: true, })`
eventually removing the loading flag solved my issue.